# how to rename object names?

Tags: php, object

i am working with fusion charts.

i have code like this

```
function get_improvement_areas_graph($param1, $param2, $repetitions, $report_type, $report_date, $sid, $graphurl)
{
$nxml=generate_improvement_areas_xml($sid,$param1,$report_type,$report_date,"graphurl");
    $graphurl = preg_replace("/\.jpg$/i", "", $graphurl); 

file_put_contents("export/$graphurl.xml", $nxml);
echo renderChart("FusionCharts/MSColumn3D.swf", "", $nxml, "$graphurl", 550, 420);
}
```

function call is in a loop. here $nxml is an object. while passing same object, chart is not working.

My question is how i can rename it for each call?

Answer (score 0):

Flash files are cached. Reloading the page won't download an updated swf. You have to delete your temporary internet file just to get a new version. One way around this is to add a dynamic variable to the swf url.

```
FusionCharts/MSColumn3D.swf?random=123
```